# abas-ERP: AJO: Getting field meaning

Tags: java, erp, abas

I have a `TypedField<CustomerEditor>` field and want to get the meaning of a field in the database.
But what I actually get is the `fieldname` like "addr" with `field.getName()`.

Is there a class or anything I have to import to get this information?

Comment: Have you tried getDescription() ? Some classes implement this function.

Comment: Yes I have. But there is no suggestion for this function. I only get `getGermanName()`, `getName()`, `getPrimaryName()` and `getQualifiedName()`. All solutions are bad and not the right one I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can imagine is getting the Value by "getTYPE"-functions (getString, getDouble, ...) of the CustomerEditor.
Imagine head is a correctly loaded CustomerEditor object:

```
TypedField<CustomerEditor> addrField = CustomerEditor.META.addr;
String addrString = head.getString(addrField);
```

If you want to get all values of a list of TypedFields you always have to differentiate between the sveral types.
Maybe this function can help you, but I never tryed myself:

```
addrField.getErpTypeInfo().getDataType()
```

I will try out some alternatives and report my results here.

Comment: The `addrField.ErpTypeInfo()` only gives me information about the database- object as itself, but no information about the name or fieldmeaning.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in an other answer, the EDProtocol is underlying AJO. EDP does not support a description info when changing fields (when applying GFV).

However, you can read the "vartab" respectively the infosystem declarations to get the meaning.